# Toggle USB power programmatically (to turn external fan on when overheating detected)

Tags: usb, power-management, overheating, fan

As an extra precaution with my home Ubuntu server, I would like to be able to remotely (or automatically) control the power to a specific USB port in order to turn a USB fan on at times when it may be running hot.

I don't need the entire solution to be provided, I suppose I only need help in achieving this via terminal commands, and I can then build controls around that myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called *PowerTOP* provided by Intel. It allows you to toggle power to attached usb devices. These are called **tunables**.

Install it by:

```
sudo apt install powertop
```

Run:

```
sudo powertop
```

http://linuxpitstop.com/install-powertop-on-ubuntu/